# how to get zoom level in react native map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm trying to calculate the zoom level when user zoom in or out, 
I find that react native maps has a onRegionChange which has longiture, latitude, longitude delta and latitude delta which (I guess) could be used to compute zoom level

from this [response](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/705#issuecomment-343781344) I tried this way:

```
 Math.round(Math.log(360 / this.state.longitudeDelta) / Math.LN2);
```

but it return a big number (which is not the zoom level).

Answer (score 6):

Write a function like below in the `onRegionChangeComplete` prop of react-native-map

```
changeRegion = debounce(async region => {
    console.log(
    Math.log2(360 * (metrics.screenWidth / 256 / region.longitudeDelta)) + 1
    );
  }, 1000);
```

or to be specific ,  `Math.log2(360 * (metrics.screenWidth / 256 / region.longitudeDelta)) + 1);` does the magic.

Answer (score 2):

```js
     <MapView
          onRegionChangeComplete={async (region) => {
            const coords = await ref?.current?.getCamera();
            console.log('coords', coords.zoom);
          }}
          ref={ref} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this solution working fine with me

Answer (score 0):

```
log2(360 * ((screenWidth/256) / region.longitudeDelta)) + 1
```

Comment: I treid this but i dont get updated zoom level on zoom in or out in render(). How to get that?